# Facebook Ask new permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've an application that only asks for "user_about_me". Now I want to ask for new permission (publish_stream) but the response object returns "connected" if the user ignores the new permission. Because I want to post to the user's wall I'll get an error when posting to the user's wall "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action".

How can I do this?

I'm using Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to handle all the possibilities for user permissions/authorization when a user logs in. Here is a simplified working example from some FB integration I have done:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    if(response.status === 'connected'){
            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(resp) {
              if(resp.data[0].publish_stream){
                  //User has permissions and authorization
              }
              else{
                  //User has not enabled publish stream, ask them to enable permission
              }
            }
}
```

If they have the permissions, I show them their avatar/username and some other options. If not, I present a link that asks them for the required permissions when clicked.